# So, who is going to record this? [piano mass torture in Philadelphia]

Tags: field-recording, crashing, piano

Any recordists living close to Philadelphia, USA looking for a nice recording opportunity?

This is in the online edition of the NY Times today:

http://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/30/arts/music/for-more-pianos-last-note-is-thud-in-the-dump.html?pagewanted=1&_r=1&hp

Quite sad but maybe at the same time a great possibility to record some crazy sounds.

Of course there's already a great 'Tortured Piano' library by Tim Prebble, but what these people are doing looks a step beyond.

Comment: @Jorg010, great heads-up! This is the type of event any sound recordist/designer should definitely seek out and make happen. Should involve some co-ordination with the people involved in the operation to insure maximum safety as well as best possible mic placements.

Comment: @Jay Jennings, yes, that's what I also thought about this opportunity. I'm in northern Europe so a recording trip to Philadelphia is unfortunately out of my reach unless I have a very specific need for these sounds in a production. But otherwise I would be very interested in the results of other recordists who might be able to pull this off because they have the chance.

Answer (score 1):

I like this idea, a lot. I'm in the northern Philly suburbs, too, so I might just be able to make it happen. It'll take some coordination, but thanks!

Comment: It would be great of you could make this recording happen! Please keep us updated.

Comment: @Jorg010 Will do!

Answer (score 0):

boy, that youtube vid linked in the article WAS hard to watch!  piano's didn't sound like much coming out of the truck either.

kind of sad.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch that was painful to watch considering a lot of working pianos meet such a cruel fate. You think there would be a business that would buy these piano's from them repair them and sell them onwards.